# Facebook signed_request cookie persist wrong code

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

I'm trying to get user pages:

```
<?php
try {
    $pages = $facebook->api('/me/accounts?fields=id,name');
    if (isset($pages['data'])) {
        $this->assign('pages', $pages['data']);
        $this->pages = $pages['data'];
    }
} catch (\FacebookApiException $e) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'redirect_uri' => $this->container->getParameter('home_url'),
            'scope'        => 'email,manage_pages'
        )
    );
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">top.location.href = "'.$loginUrl.'";</script>';
    exit;
}
```

but I jump into endless redirect loop. After some research I found out that PHP SDK get's an error from API in `getAccessTokenFromCode` method. [`$access_token_response`](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L775) variable is:

```
{"error":{"message":"This authorization code has expired.","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}
```

PHP SDK takes `code` value from COOKIE. The problem is that `fbsr_{app_id}` is not flushed and it still contains the same code. And that's the reason for endless loop.

What can I do to overcome this problem. I was thinking about deleting `fbsr_{app_id}` cookie but it looks weird. Why does SDK not handle this for me?

Comment: I know you found a workaround for this older issue, but it's definitely a problem. Even after deleting that cookie, the JS SDK still generates a signed_request with a previously used code. I keep meaning to create a reproducible scenario and report as a bug to them. Just came across it in the 11th hour of trying to get an app pushed live.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP 5.4, I ran into this issue too. I wrote up a [tutorial](https://www.webniraj.com/2012/12/19/facebook-php-sdk-fixing-getuser-on-php-5-4-x/) on how to fix the issue. The reason was the PHP SDK wasn't picking up the code correctly.

You could also try to destroy the session (`session_destroy()` or the Framework equivalent) or manually clear the cookies (`setcookie ("cookie_name", "", time() - 3600);`) if a exception is received.

**EDIT**:

Make sure the App ID and App Secret in the app are correct too. An incorrect app secret is sometimes the issue as it's used to decode the `signed_request`.

Also, if the problem is specific to IE, try adding the following header to your code:

```
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT');
```

IE's security settings sometimes prevent cookies from setting in iframes. The above header should help.

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.3.5. The problem here is with cookie containing signed_request as it does not change.

Comment: Is it specific to the browser you are using?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I found workaround. I'm using both PHP SDK and JS SDK. I used following code for redirection:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">top.location.href = "'.$loginUrl.'";</script>';
exit;
```

But I added JS SDK to it and problem does not occur anymore:

```
echo "
<div id=\"fb-root\"></div>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: ".$app_id.", status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true});
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        top.location.href = '".$loginUrl."';
    });
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
";
exit;
```

I'm not sure if it's not a bug of JS SDK/PHP SDK.